# TypeError (unorderable types: int() <= NoneType())

Tags: python, types

This is my first time writing code in Python and could use some help. I am using Python 34 and simply cannot understand what is going on.

```
def roll(v):
    x = input()
    return (x + v)

def startGame():
    v = 0
    while 0 <= v: # error points to this line
        v = roll(v)  

print("Thanks for playing")
```

I declare v to be an integer with a  value of 0. But when I try to compare it to another integer, it gives me the  error message `unorderable types: int() <= NoneType()`
I could use some guidance..
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you've a `return` statement in `roll`?

Comment: Very first skill to gain with every programming is properly formatting the code. You shall indent the line follwoing `while` one four characters to the right. And make sure, if you want your final `print` line to be part of function startGame or of the script as a whole.

Comment: If this is Python3, then `input` will produce a string, so there's probably a problem with `(x + v)`. Also, where do you call `startGame`?

Comment: The code you've posted will run without errors, but it won't actually do anything as you aren't actually calling `startGame()`. Please copy and paste the exact code that generates the error: often people copy what they think is the relevant part of the code and inadvertantly fix the error as they do.

Comment: Not the cause of the error, but you probably meant `while v <= 0:`, otherwise you will likely have an infinite loop (unless the user inputs negative numbers).

Comment: Downvote as you evidently did not google for your error message or used basic debugging. A search for `type error unorderable types` gives FOUR stackoverflow questions as the first four results which should have given you an idea of the error. Furthermore, you could have just printed `v` on every iteration to see that it's not what you expect it to be...

Comment: 14mpi my very first line of the post states "This is my first time writing code in Python". The google solutions didn't quite help as I had no idea what I was even looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I placed the code you posted into a python 3 shell but it fails somewhere else. Your x = input() produces a string, and python doesn't know how to convert strings to numbers unless you explicitly tell it how.

so:

```
def roll(v)
    # Lets try to parse userinput
    try:
        x = int(input())
    # sometimes users don't get it that "a" is no int
    except ValueError:
        x = 0
    return (x+v)
```

or

```
def roll(v)
    hasProducedNumber = False
    x = 0
    # we keep nagging for a number till no valueerror arises
    while not hasProducedNumber:
        try:
            x = int(input())
            hasProducedNumber = True
        except ValueError:
            print("Please provide a number")

    return (x + v)
```

If this is not a solution to your problem I need relevant code that actually produces your error :)

Comment: A flag variable is not required here, better use `while True` with either `break` or `return (x+v)`.

Comment: In my opinion breaks are just as ugly as gotos. Making it verbose like this was completely on purpose.

Comment: Thanks guys windwarrior your solution helped. I had to cast my input as an int

Comment: Be sure to also look at the try block around it, it is good practice never to trust input from users and always check that your user fills in ints when he should. This is for example what happened with HeartBleed, the guy responsible for the bug assumed that some data from a user was *always* correct, but didn't validate it.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
def roll(v):
    x = int(input('Please insert value of x: '))
    return (x + v)
```

Comment: Thanks M. Adel. This was the solution as well