# Min value from list witout None values

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, min

I have to get min value from list with loop but I get an error:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 6, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < NoneType()
```

Here is my code:

```
tab = [1,2,3,4, None, None, None]

min_value = None
for i in tab:
  if i:
    if int(i) < min_value:
      min_value = i
      print(min_value)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError (unorderable types: int() <= NoneType())](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23364190/typeerror-unorderable-types-int-nonetype)

Comment: What result do you expect from comparing an int to `None` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `min_value` to something numeric rather than to None.

```
min_value = float("inf")
```

You can also use the `min()` function for this sort of thing:

```
min(v for v in tab if v is not None)
```

Answer (score 2):

Little simpler

```
tab = [1,2,3,4, None, None, None]

print(min([i for i in tab if not i == None]))
```

Comment: what if i is 0? Use explicitly `i != None`

Comment: The canonical way to check whether something isn't `None` is by identity, since that's a singleton object: `if i is not None`. (And `not i == None` would be a little tidier as `i != None`.)

Answer (score 1):

You declared an initial value of `None`, which can't be compared to numbers. Try a very high value that's unlikely to be in the list - or, better yet, simply grab the first item of the list and use that. Make sure to set it to 0 if it gets something falsey (similar to what you're doing in the loop with `if i:`).

You can combine the conditions for setting a new `min_value` with the `and` logical operator.

Also, put the `print` call outside the loop, so you only print the final value.

```
tab = [1,2,3,4, None, None, None]

min_value = tab[0] or 0
for i in tab:
    if i and int(i) < min_value:
            min_value = i

print(min_value)
```